# Upload a file by Ajax without submitting the form

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I want to upload a file by Ajax (without submitting the form) than process in backend, and clear the field to allow to add another file. Is it possible with Drupal 8? Can anyone provide an example?

I tried this one but without success.

```
$form['input']['file'] = array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#upload_location' => "public://$file_dir/",
  "#upload_validators" => array(
    'my_file_validator' => array(),
  ),
);
```

My questions are:
1. How to add an extra process callback (backend) ?
2. How to clear the field (Front end) ?

Thank you
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This code uploads one file with Ajax, attaching it to an existing node's file field. The content type is file_test, and the field is field_da_files.

(I'm not a professional programmer, so there are no doubt better ways to do this.)

Here's some HTML/JS that talks to a Drupal controller. It sends the node id, and the file to be stored.

In uptest.html.twig:

```
<p>NID <input type="text" id="nid" name="nid"></p>
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
<input type="button" class="button" value="Upload" id="but_upload">
```

In library JS file:

```
(function($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.uptestInitialized = false;
  Drupal.behaviors.uptest = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      if (Drupal.uptestInitialized) {
        return;
      }
      Drupal.uptestInitialized = true;
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#but_upload").click(function() {
          var fd = new FormData();
          var files = $('#file')[0].files[0];
          if (! files) {
            alert("No files");
            return;
          }
          var nid = $("#nid").val();
          if (! nid) {
            alert("No nid");
            return;
          }
          fd.append('nid', nid);
          fd.append('file', files);

          $.ajax({
            url: '/uptest-save',
            type: 'post',
            data: fd,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response){
              let result = response.success;
              if (result){
                alert('yay!');
              }
              else {
                let msg = response.message;
                alert('file not uploaded: ' + msg);
              }
            },
          });
        });
      })
}}})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Routing file:

```
uptest.default_controller_hello:
  path: '/uptest'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\uptest\Controller\DefaultController::hello'
    _title: 'uptest'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'

uptest.default_controller_upload:
  path: '/uptest-save'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\uptest\Controller\DefaultController::saveFile'
    _title: 'Save'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

In the controller:

```
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use \Drupal\Component\Utility\Bytes;

public function hello() {
  $renderable = [
    '#theme' => 'uptest',
    '#cache' => [
      'max-age' => 0,
    ],
    '#attached' => [
      'library' => [
        'uptest/uptest',
      ],
    ],
  ];
  return $renderable;
}

public function saveFile(Request $request) {
  $nid = $request->get('nid');
  if (!$nid || !is_numeric($nid) || $nid < 0) {
    return $this->makeUploadErrorResponse('Bad NID format');
  }
  $node = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')
    ->load($nid);
  if (!$node) {
    return $this->makeUploadErrorResponse('No node with nid of ' . $nid);
  }
  /** @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $uploadedFile */
  $uploadedFile = $request->files->get('file');
  if (!$uploadedFile->isValid()) {
    return $this->makeUploadErrorResponse('Invalid file upload.');
  }
  //Get uploaded file metadata.
  $uploadedFileName = $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName();
  $uploadedFileExtension = $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $uploadedFileSize = $uploadedFile->getClientSize();
  $uploadedFilePath = $uploadedFile->getPathname();
  //Get node field metadata.
  $nodeFieldMetadata = $this->getFileFieldMetaData('file_test', 'field_da_files');
  if (!$nodeFieldMetadata) {
    return $this->makeUploadErrorResponse('Problem loading file field metadata.');
  }
  //Check uploaded file's extension.
  $allowedExtensions = explode(' ', $nodeFieldMetadata['extensions']);
  if (!in_array($uploadedFileExtension, $allowedExtensions)) {
    return $this->makeUploadErrorResponse('Extension not allowed.');
  }
  //Check the file size.
  $maxSizeAllowed = Bytes::toInt($nodeFieldMetadata['max file size']);
  if ($uploadedFileSize > $maxSizeAllowed) {
    return $this->makeUploadErrorResponse('File too large.');
  }
  //Check cardinality.
  /** @var \Drupal\file\Plugin\Field\FieldType\FileFieldItemList $fieldValueInNode */
  $fieldValueInNode = $node->get('field_da_files');
  $fieldAttachedFileItemList = $fieldValueInNode->getValue();
  $nodeFileFieldNumAttachments = count($fieldAttachedFileItemList);
  $allowedCardinality = $nodeFieldMetadata['cardinality'];
  if ($nodeFileFieldNumAttachments >= $allowedCardinality) {
    return $this->makeUploadErrorResponse('Maximum number of files for this node already reached.');
  }
  //OK. Attach the file.
  //Prepare the directory.
  $directory = 'private://' . $nodeFieldMetadata['directory'];
  $result = file_prepare_directory($directory, FileSystemInterface::CREATE_DIRECTORY);
  if (!$result) {
    return $this->makeUploadErrorResponse('Error preparing directory.');
  }
  //Read the file's contents.
  $fileData = file_get_contents($uploadedFilePath);
  //Save in right dir, creating a file entity instance.
  $savedFile = file_save_data($fileData,
    $directory . '/' . $uploadedFileName,
    FileSystemInterface::EXISTS_RENAME
  );
  if (!$savedFile) {
    return $this->makeUploadErrorResponse('Error saving file.');
  }
  //Attach to the node.
  $node->field_da_files[] = [
    'target_id' => $savedFile->id(),
  ];
  $node->save();
  return new JsonResponse([
    'success' => TRUE,
  ]);
}

/**
 * Make a response for file upload attempt with an error message.
 *
 * @param string $message The error message.
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse Response to return to client.
 */
protected function makeUploadErrorResponse($message) {
  $result = [
    'success' => FALSE,
    'message' => $message,
  ];
  return new JsonResponse($result);
}

/**
 * Get metadata for a file field.
 *
 * @param string $contentType Content type with the field.
 * @param string $fieldName Name of the field.
 *
 * @return array|bool Metadata, or false if a problem.
 */
public function getFileFieldMetaData($contentType, $fieldName) {
  if ($contentType === '' || $fieldName === '') {
    return FALSE;
  }
  $entityFieldManager = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager');
  $fields = $entityFieldManager->getFieldDefinitions('node', $contentType);
  if (!$fields || count($fields) === 0) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  //Get file field definition.
  if (!isset($fields[$fieldName])) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  /** @var \Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig $fieldDef */
  $fieldDef = $fields[$fieldName];
  //Get settings, doesn't include cardinality.
  $directory = $fieldDef->getSetting('file_directory');
  //Resolve tokens.
  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Utility\Token $tokenService */
  $tokenService = \Drupal::service('token');
  $directory = $tokenService->replace($directory);
  $fileExtensions = $fieldDef->getSetting('file_extensions');
  $maxFileSize = $fieldDef->getSetting('max_filesize');
  //Get cardinality.
  /** @var \Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig $fieldStorageDef */
  $fieldStorageDef = $fieldDef->getFieldStorageDefinition();
  $cardinality = $fieldStorageDef->getCardinality();
  //Return results.
  $result = [
    'content type' => $contentType,
    'field' => $fieldName,
    'directory' => $directory,
    'extensions' => $fileExtensions,
    'max file size' => $maxFileSize,
    'cardinality' => $cardinality,
  ];
  return $result;
}
```

Hope that helps.